# creating dataset/storing vectors from c++ to python

Tags: dataset, pandas, data

I am new to the data science field.
I need to create dataset which consists of n inputs (vectors of size 5) and n outputs (vectors of size > 10,000). These vectors are generated using c++ code.
What is the best way to store them, such that they can be easily readable in python and use to train tensorflow/keras network?

I am looking for recommendation on format and tools to be used.

Comment: The easiest way is to store them as text file, for instance CSV.